# Generate Javadoc in Netbeans is disabled

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, javadoc

I been looking around for hours and can't seem to find a solution to my problem. I am using Netbeans 8 and I would like to generate a Javadoc. I have formatted my comments to match Javadoc format. But the action menu (generate Javadoc) is disabled to any of the project.

How can I enable it? My project can be seen here: https://github.com/Daytron/SimpleDialogFX

Comment: ?? http://spartanideas.msu.edu/2014/06/23/netbeans-8-update-bugs/ - restart your IDE?

Comment: I saw that and tried many times. But to no avail. :(

Comment: NFI man, it works on a clean netbeans install with your project. (8.0.2 - latest)

Comment: Is it possible to re-enable it without re-installing Netbeans?

Comment: I have no idea what is preventing it from being enabled to suggest a workaround; I was mentioning that it *works on my machine*. I'd check if you're missing an update that may address the issue.

Comment: Ok I found a workaround but using a Maven plugin and works great, still no clue why in Netbeans it is disabled.

Answer (score 1):

I see that you are using Maven for your project. NetBeans' support for Maven is best-in-class since you almost never need to add anything to your Maven project in order for NetBeans to load it properly. To enable Javadoc during your build, simply add the following code to the `<plugins>` element within your `<build>` element.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.10.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>attach-javadocs</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Note: Since generating Javadoc may take a bit of time and those outputs are not necessary for debugging, I recommend only enabling the Javadoc output for a final build. However, the simplest path is certainly to just enable it all the time, which is what I've shown above.

Comment: Yes I mentioned this earlier on one of the comments, I did managed to use this as opposed to IDE's feature. But, I am still hoping to find a way to enable the IDE feature. Thanks though.

Answer (score 1):

Netbeans 8 needs to be restarted sometimes to show the Generate Javadoc.